# Magento 2.3.5 SOAP DateTime is invalid

Tags: soap, magento2.3.5

Running the very basic SOAP request to list all services:

```
soap/default?wsdl_list=1
```

I get

**The "\DateTime" parameter type is invalid. Verify the parameter and try again.**

[image]

Comment: This only happened after upgrading to Magento 2.3.5 from 2.3.2

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a Dotmailer bug: https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/issues/560

Upgrade or remove the module.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with updating the extension due to composer conflicts. I used following to bypass it. Just add this to `composer.json` file.

```
"replace": {
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat": "*"
    }
```

And run

```
composer install
```

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28244#issuecomment-630077997